# Adding extra fields for an AddressBook contact using iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, contacts, custom-fields

I was new in iPhone application development. As i might have gone through native applications, i was struggling from 1 week, for adding new fields to a particular contact of AddressBook.

As we might have known that it is not possible to edit addressBook details, i want to bind those values to sqlite3 table & then i thought to add new fields to selected contact.

Can anyOne of you push me out of this situation..?
(Plz,provide me with the Sample Code to test.)

Note: AS I have no device,i need to test it using iPhone Simulator. Let me know, would it be Possible or not?

Thanks & Regards,

Ramya.

Answer (score 0):

See these questions:

[iPhone Address Book custom property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122592/iphone-address-book-custom-property)
[iPhone: Create Custom Field in contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257120/iphone-create-custom-field-in-contacts)

Comment: @ Jeff Kelley,
Thank you so much for providing me the links.I already had a look on those. I worked with displaying contacts list in my apps using AddressBook Framework. But, i want to store the AddressBook values in a "contacts" table of sqlite3 database.how can i pass AddressBook data to insert into contacts table using sqlite3 commands..can you provide me with an example?

Comment: I wrote up a blog post on getting the addresses out of contacts. You can use the functions in it to get at whatever data you need.

http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2009/01/21/cocoa-touch-tutorial-extract-address-book-address-values-on-iphone-os/

Comment: Thank You,Let me tell you a-bit clear what i need is?
I need to insert the addressbook contacts in my own database with the help of sqlite3.So,to insert values into my table ,i am using the query like:  insert into Contacts(FirstName, Phoneno, Email) Values(?,?,?) . I want to use this query for inserting addressbook values into contacts table of my database. Would it be possible?If Yes, please help me..

Comment: Like I said, read the blog post. For instance, this returns someone's first name:


`ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)`


where `person` is an `ABRecordRef`.

Comment: (1)Yes,OfCourse. Is it possible to get all properties of a person at a time. If yes,how? 

(2)If not possible, how can i use this kABFirstNameProperty in  sqlite3 insert command.

(3)As person is an instance of ABPersonViewController class,is it possible to use it in another method/class?
Please guide me the way...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm not going to write all your code for you. I've given you more than enough resources to accomplish your goal.